# SpringBoot MapStruct Mapping Entity to DTO with Relationship Entities

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct, mapper

I am using the MapStruct library for mapping objects, and I need to translate from an entity to a dto, but there is a problem, for example, that the entity stores animal types as a list of objects, and the dto stores an array with the ids of these types. how can this be done correctly? I did it, but only manually using loops. MapStruct is something new for me, so a lot of things are not clear, I hope for your help, thanks!

I have this class:

```
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Table(name = "animal")
public class Animal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @MinCollectionSize
    @ElementOfCollectionNotNull
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "animal_types",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "animal_id",referencedColumnName = "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "type_id",referencedColumnName = "id")})
    List<AnimalType> animalTypes;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    Float weight;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    Float length;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    Float height;

    @NotNull
    @NotGender
    AnimalGender gender;

    AnimalLifeStatus lifeStatus;

    TimestampWithTimeZoneJdbcType chippingDateTime;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chipper_id")
    Account chipperId;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chipping_location_id")
    Location chippingLocationId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "animal")
    List<AnimalLocation> visitedLocations;

    TimestampWithTimeZoneJdbcType deathDateTime;

}
```

And i need this Entity mapping to this DTO:

```
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class AnimalResponse {
    Long id;
    Long[] animalTypes;
    Float weight;
    Float length;
    Float height;
    AnimalGender gender;
    AnimalLifeStatus lifeStatus;
    TimestampWithTimeZoneJdbcType chippingDateTime;
    Integer chippedId;
    Long chippingLocationId;
    Long[] visitedLocations;
    TimestampWithTimeZoneJdbcType deathDateTime;
}
```

This is my Mapper Interfaces:

```
public interface BaseMapper<ENTITY, DTO> {

    DTO toDto(ENTITY entity);
    ENTITY toEntity(DTO dto);
    List<DTO> toDtoList(List<ENTITY> entityList);
    List<ENTITY> toEntityList(List<DTO> dtoList);

}
```

```
@Mapper
public interface AnimalMapper extends BaseMapper<Animal, AnimalResponse> {
    AnimalMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(AnimalMapper.class);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert List of Objects to List of Long IDs using Mapstruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68123670/convert-list-of-objects-to-list-of-long-ids-using-mapstruct)

Comment: to not List<Long>, to array of longs like long[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Mapper
public interface AnimalMapper extends BaseMapper<Animal, AnimalResponse> {
    
    AnimalMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(AnimalMapper.class);
    
    @Override
    @Named("toDto")
    @Mapping(source = "animalTypes", target = "animalTypes", qualifiedByName = "toArray")
    AnimalResponse toDto(Animal entity);
    
    @Override
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "toDto")
    List<AnimalResponse> toDtoList(List<Animal> entityList);
    
    @Override
    @Named("toEntity")
    @Mapping(source = "animalTypes", target = "animalTypes", qualifiedByName = "toArrayList")
    Animal toEntity(AnimalResponse dto);
    
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "toEntity")
    List<Animal> toEntityList(List<AnimalResponse> dtoList);
    
    @Named("toArray") 
    default Long[] toArray(List<AnimalType> animalTypes) { 
        return animalTypes.stream()
                          .map(AnimalType::getId)
                          .toArray(size -> new Long[size]);
    }
    
    @Named("toArrayList") 
    default List<AnimalType> toArrayList(Long[] animalTypes) { 
        return Arrays.stream(animalTypes)
                     .map(AnimalType::new) // new object just for example purposes, you can instead call the repository findById
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
}
```

With the following animal:

```
Animal(id=1, animalTypes=[AnimalType(id=1), AnimalType(id=2), AnimalType(id=3)])
```

the generated response by calling toDto

```
AnimalResponse response = AnimalMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(animal);
```

will be:

```
AnimalResponse(id=1, animalTypes=[1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: and another question, if i have other array of long like long[] visitedLocation, i need to use ```@Mapping(source = "visitedLocations", target = "visitedLocations",qualifiedByName = "toArray")```?

Comment: The arrays takes the long value from different Object, so no, you can’t use the same method. You need to declare a new one with another name and use it for the “qualifiedByName” attribute.

Comment: Unless you want to use Java Reflection

Comment: visitedLocations takes from same Object

Comment: I’m referring on the long values, for animalTypes the long value is the id of AnimalType, but for visitedLocations the long value is the id of AnimalLocation. So the only way to reuse the method “toArray” is to implement it using Java Reflection, or changing the entities to extend a class or implement an interface with common getter so Java Generics can be used.